# Replace a substring with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Need to replace a substring in URL (technically just a string) with javascript.
The string like

```
http://blah-blah.com/search?par_one=test&par_two=anothertest&SearchableText=TO_REPLACE
```

or

```
http://blah-blah.com/search?par_one=test&SearchableText=TO_REPLACE&par_two=anothertest
```

means, the word to replace can be either at the most end of the URL or in the middle of it.
I am trying to cover these with the following:

```
var newWord = NEW_SEARCH_TERM;
var str = 'http://blah-blah.com/search?par_one=test&SearchableText=TO_REPLACE&par_two=anothertest';
var regex = /^\S+SearchableText=(.*)&?\S*$/;
str = str.replace(regex, newWord);
```

But no matter what I do I get str = NEW_SEARCH_TERM. Moreover the regular expression when I try it in RegExhibit, selects the word to replace and everything that follows it that is not what I want.

How can I write a universal expression to cover both cases and make the correct string be saved in the variable?

Comment: 1. This looks like Plone, which already depends on jQuery. Why not use $.query.get?

Comment: Yes, it's Plone, kojiro. But I don't want to depend on plugins. Seems like $.query.get is not standard function of jQuery and is provided by [Query String Object extension](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object). So, not what I really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.replace(/SearchableText=[^&]*/, 'SearchableText=' + newWord)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\S+` and `\S*` in your regex match all non-whitespace characters.

You probably want to remove them and the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ZGbsY/

ClyFish did it while I was fiddling

```
var url1="http://blah-blah.com/search?par_one=test&par_two=anothertest&SearchableText=TO_REPLACE";

var url2 ="http://blah-blah.com/search?par_one=test&SearchableText=TO_REPLACE&par_two=anothertest"

var newWord = "foo";
function replaceSearch(str,newWord) {
  var regex = /SearchableText=[^&]*/;

  return str.replace(regex, "SearchableText="+newWord);
}
document.write(replaceSearch(url1,newWord))
document.write('<hr>');
document.write(replaceSearch(url2,newWord))
```